# How to keep an UIButton highlighted once it was pressed?

Tags: ios4

I have a UIScroll view and there are some UIButton (actually each button is representing a photo, just like the photo app in iPhone.)

`UIImage *photo = [photoArray objectAtIndex:i];
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

My question is when "EDIT" button (an UIBarButtonItem) is pressed, user can click more that one photo, let say 10 photos, and then he can click "delete" or "blah blah blah" button, etc, to have some actions on selected photos.

So to distinguish what photos are currently selected, I want to keep them Highlighted,
and I tried to use "setHighlighted" but this fails ( just highlighted for 0.0001 second >< )

So I hope that you all could give me some suggestion !
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try putting this UIImage&UIButton inside a UIView..
and when this UIButton is clicked change the color of corresponding UIView..